# php test if string ends with _text + number

Tags: php

I have a couple of issues with this if statement which checks if a string ends with "address".

E.g this matches `user_address`, `user_address1`, `user_address99`, etc. Which is correct.

The problem is that it also matches `user_address_location` which is not correct.

I only want this to match if:

1. Is ends with _address
2. Also if it has a number on the end e.g _address2

```
/* Only establish an address field as ADDRESS if follows "user_address1" format */
if((stristr($column,"address") !== false)) {
    $parts = explode("_", $column);
    if (!empty($parts)) {
        // address code
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you control your field names?  If so put a _ between address and the number eg user_address_2 user_address_33  then you can use explode('_',$name) to get the values, if the last value is a number you have your address

Comment: I think I have figured out a way to do this without the extra _

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a decent place to use a regex

```
if(preg_match('/^user_addesss\d*$/', $column) === 1){
}
```

Comment: My method without regular expression is faster

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
if(preg_match('/_address(\d+)?$/', $column))
{

}
```

if you are doing a lot of string comparing and manipulation this web application will be very useful to you: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

It allows you to develop regular expressions against content with live feedback on matches and replacements.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `$` of regular expressions here. When using regular expressions `$` specifies the end of a string

So, you can search for this regular expression:

```
$regexp = "^.*_address\d+$";
```

`^` is the start, `.*` indicates any number of any characters `_address` is what you want to search for, `\d+` says it can have numbers after address, and `$` indicates end of string.

You can read more about regular expressions, and `preg_match` on php.net

Answer (score 0):

change `if((stristr($column,"address") !== false)) {` to `if(preg_match("/^user_address[0-9]*/", $column) == 1) {`

Comment: This will only match one number at the end of the line. Since the OP wants to match zero or more numbers, it should end with `[0-9]*`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to find a way to do it without regular expressions, sorry I should of made that clear in the question.

But I think I have found a way, not sure if it can be improved or performance compared to the regular expressions.

```
/* First establish it could be an address field e.g "user_address1" format */
$column_address = strpos($column, "_address");
if($column_address !== false) {

    // remove everything before "_address"
    $last = substr($column, $column_address);

    // Check if "_address" OR remove "_address" and check if int
    if($last == "_address" || intval(substr($last, 8))){
```

Comment: Seems a little overkill to be honest.  They developed regular expressions so we wouldn't have to do this sort of thing.  But if it works for you there is no reason not to do it your way.

Comment: @DavidThomas - that question is now undeleted